# $E$ is a certain subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Is the set $\{x − 2, (x − 2)^2, (x − 2)^3\}$ a basis of $E$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question goals

> Recall that we use the symbol $\mathbb R[x]$ to mean the real vector space of all polynomials in $x$ with real coefficients. Show that the set
>   $$
> E=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]:\, p(2)=0 \, \, \text{and} \, \, \deg(p(x))\le 3\}
> $$
>
> is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Is the set $\{x − 2, (x − 2)^2, (x − 2)^3\}$ a basis of $E$?

I'm a bit confused. I had a look at my notes I think I might be able to use 6 of the 10 "vector space axioms". But that's just because it's a similar question. I'm not too sure with this content. I was going to go look for a linear combination.

Comment: To show that E is a subspace of the given vector space, you just need to show that 1) it is closed under addition and 2) it is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Let $$
E'=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]:\, p(0)=0 \, \, and \, \, \deg(p(x))\le 3\}
$$

>Is $E'$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x]$? Is the set $\{x , x ^2, x ^3\}$ a basis of $E'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guide you. $E$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ ($0\in E$). So to prove that $E$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, why not simply use the following theorem?

> **Subspace Criterion**
>
> Let $S$ be a subset of the real vector space $V$. Then $S$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if:
>
> $(i)\,\,0\in S$
>
> $(ii)\,\,\forall v_1,v_2\in S,\,v_1+v_2\in S$
>
> $(iii)\forall v\in S,\,\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R},\,\alpha v\in S$

Now $\mathcal{B}=\{(x-2),\,(x-2)^2,\,(x-2)^3\}$ is a basis of $E$, if it is linearly independent and generates $E$, i.e, $\text{span}((x-2),(x-2)^2,(x-2)^3)=E$. Proving that $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent shouldn't be hard. Let $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma\in \mathbb{R}$ such as $\alpha (x-2)+\beta (x-2)^2+\gamma (x-2)^3=0$. Expand this and write it in the form $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$ and so $A=B=C=D=0$. Then you must find that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$. Another easier way is to differentiate $\alpha (x-2)+\beta (x-2)^2+\gamma (x-2)^3=0$ as many ways necessary to get rid of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but still have $\gamma$ and so you'll find that $\gamma =0$ and so on...

Proving that $\mathcal{B}$ spans $E$ isn't really hard. Let $P\in E$ . Then $P(x)=(x-2)(ax^2+bx+c)$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ (you should use $P(2)=0$ and $\deg(P)\le3$ to see why). Let's focus on Q(x)=$ax^2+bx+c$ and see if it can be written as a linear combinaison of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. First put $y=x-2$. Then $Q(x)=a(y+2)^2+b(y+2)+c$. If you expand it, it'll be of the form $Q(x)=my^2+ny+q$ for some $m,n,q\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y=x-2$. Back to $P(x)=(x-2)Q(x)$ conclude that $P$ is a linear combinaison of vectors of $\mathcal{B}$.

---

This is an important result:

> Let $\mathcal{F}=\{P_1,\,P_2,\,\dots ,P_n\}$ be a family of nonzero vectors of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Prove that if they all have different degrees then $\mathcal{F}$ is linearly independent.

Try to prove it! You can do as I proposed to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: How did you prove that that A = B = C = D = 0? For linear independence?

Comment: We know that two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the same degree and the coefficients of the monomials with the same degree are equal, right? You can use this for the case of a polynomial equal to zero: its coefficients must be all equal to 0. You can also convince yourself by derivating $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$ three times and you'll get $6A=0$ and so $A=0$...

Answer (score 3):

The first part has already been answered in the comment by uer84413.

As for the second part: calculate the polynomials $(x-2)^2$ and $(x-2)^3$. Then it should be easy for you to prove that $x-2, (x-2)^2$ and $(x-2)^3$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

You only need these three conditions to check if it is a subspace-(first one is not necessary but rather fun)

1. $0\in E$, clearly.
2. **Closure under addition-** Let $a(x),b(x) \in E$, then $a(2)+b(2)=0+0=0$ and $\deg(a+b) \le \max\{\deg(a),\deg(b)\} \le 3$, hence satisfied.
3. **Closure under scalar multiplication**- If $a\in \Bbb{R}$ and $p(x)\in E$, does $g(x)a.p(x)\in E$? Clearly $g(2)=0$, check the other condition too.

So it is a subspace.

To check the set $S=\{x − 2, (x − 2)^2, (x − 2)^3\}$ a basis try proving linear independence i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i(x-2)^i=0 \iff a_i=0\ \forall\ i=1,2,3$ by expanding and comparing coefficients and to prove that every element of $E$ lies in span of $S$, let $y=x-2$ and prove $\{y,y^2,y^3\}$ spans $E'=\{f'(x)\in \Bbb{R}[x] : f'(0)=0 \text{and}\ \deg\ f'(x) \le 3\}$ as $E\cong E'$